# How do I use a for loop to store function output in separate variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have the following function:

```
 def function3(start, end):
    """Read MO information."""
    config_found = False
    var = []
    for line in v['molecular orbital primitive coefficients']:
        if line.strip() == end:
            config_found = False
        elif config_found:
            i = line.rstrip()
            var.append(i)
        elif line.strip() == start:
            config_found = True
    var1 = [elem.strip() for elem in var]
    var2 = var1[1:-1]
    var3 = np.array([line.split() for line in var2])
    var3 = np.asarray([list(map(float, item)) for item in var3])
    return var3
```

And suppose I store its output in variables like so:

```
    monumber1=function3('1','2')
    monumber2=function3('2','3')
    monumber3=function3('3','4')
```

etc.

Is there a way for me to execute this function a set number of times and store the output in a set number of variables without manually setting the variable name and function arguments every time? Maybe using a for loop? This is my attempt, but I'm struggling to make it functional:

```
 for i in xrange(70):
    monumber[x] = function3([i],[i+1])
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use dynamic variables, **use a container like a `list` or a `dict`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your use of square brackets. Here is code that should work:

```
monumber = [] # make it an empty list
for i in xrange(70):
    monumber.append(function3(str(i),str(i+1))) # you had string integers, so cast
```

For the more Pythonic one-liner, you can use a list comprehension:

```
monumber = [function3(str(i),str(i+1)) for i in xrange(70)]
```

Now that the `monumber` variable has been created, I can access the element at any given index `i` using the syntax `monumber[i]`. Some examples:

```
first = monumber[0] # gets the first element of monumber
last = monumber[-1] # gets the last index of monumber
for i in xrange(10,20): # starts at i = 10 and ends at i = 19
    print(monumber[i])  # print the i-th element of monumber
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Can I ask you another question? How can I store each output in an individual variable? For instance, how can I access monumber[1] specifically?

Comment: Remember that Python is 0-based, so `monumber[0]` is the first element of `monumber`. To access any given element, you use the exact syntax you mentioned: `monumber[i]` accesses the element of `monumber` at index `i`. I'll update my answer with some examples

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it. Except you should use `i` on the left hand side, too:

```
monumber[i] = function3([i],[i+1])
```

Now, this is the basic idea, but the code will only work if `monumber` is already a list with enough elements, otherwise an `IndexError` will occur.

Instead of creating a list and filling it with placeholders in advance, we can dynamically append new values to it:

```
monumber = []
for i in xrange(70):
    monumber.append(function3([i],[i+1]))
```

Another problem is that you seem to be confusing different types of arguments that your function works with. In the function body, it looks like `start` and `end` are strings, but in your code, you give to **lists** with one **integer** each. Without changing the function, you can do:

```
monumber = []
for i in xrange(70):
    monumber.append(function3(str(i),str(i+1)))
```

Comment: The square brackets seem incorrect, though. In OP's example, the parameters of `function3` are strings (`'1'`, `'2'`, etc.). I think you should cast `i` and `i+1` to strings instead of making 1-element lists (i.e., `str(i)` and `str(i+1)` instead of `[i]` and `[i+1]`)